# How do I create a VM when every US region seems to be out of compute resources?

Tags: azure

I am finding it impossible to create a general purpose Linux VM with 4 vCPU and 8-16 GB RAM. There is such little availability that by the time I have requested a quota for the specific VM type (out of 50+), that specific family is no longer available. I even have gotten to the point where a VM is available in the portal, so I go to create it with the CLI and by the time I hit enter, the API responds that that SKU is no longer available in the region.

I am paying $30/month so I can submit support tickets and another ~$10/month for Azure AD with my domain name, so I am not getting blocked by free/student account quotas. I understand that is pennies for Microsoft but experiences like this are how people end up on Google or AWS when you can get VM's instantly. And we all know about the snowball effect of cloud lock-in.

Answer (score 0):

From Azure for the [student account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/free/students/) its only available to use ***B1s burstable virtual machines*** .B1s virtual machines comes with lower configuration you can check the same [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request#:%7E:text=%20To%20start%20a%20support%20request%20from%20anywhere,your%20problem.%20We%27ll%20suggest%20some%20possible...%20See%20More.?msclkid=7f6a16aab01811ec90790a1591d8fa7a)

AFAIK, Its not possible to `create a general purpose Linux VM with 4 vCPU and 8-16 GB RAM` in student account.

As you are paying $30/month please reach out to [*Azure support*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request#:%7E:text=%20To%20start%20a%20support%20request%20from%20anywhere,your%20problem.%20We%27ll%20suggest%20some%20possible...%20See%20More.?msclkid=7f6a16aab01811ec90790a1591d8fa7a) ,to check the availability for the general purpose VM with higher configurations will supported in student account or not.

For more information please refer this ***MS Q&A***: [***Size not available error, the size is currently unavilable in southcentralus***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/695791/size-not-available-error-the-size-is-currently-una.html)